# Registering user inactivity in QT for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qwidget, pyside2

I'm trying to trigger a function when any space or object within my main window recieves a mouse click. The purpose for doing so is to reset a timer when an interaction is recorded so that if the timer reaches X it will open a password request window (e.g. no interaction after 5 minutes, timer reaches 300 and an if function closes/opens windows)

QWidgets do not have a "pressed" or "release" signal, so have tried working around this with the mousePressEvent function. This won't do however as any child widgets will have their own mousePressEvent event handler, and there are many of these child widgets that will eventually be created dynamically.

I've created a test program to explain what i want to do:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.label = QLabel("0")
        self.button = QPushButton("press")
        self.label2 = QLabel("TESTING")
        self.label2.setStyleSheet("background: orange;")

        #self.button.released.connect(self.reset)

        self.y = 0

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_label)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #self.button.underMouse()
        self.reset()

    def update_label(self):
        self.y += 1
        print(self.y)
        if self.y == 5:
            print("hello!")
        self.label.setText(str(self.y))

    def reset(self):
        self.y = 0


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

To better understand what i mean, if you click anywhere in this window, the `reset` function is called and `self.y` resets to 0, however if you click the button, it won't.

According to the documentation at: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html?highlight=qwidget#events child widgets can have their mousePressEvent's called by placing `underMouse()` inside `mousePressEvent`' but this doesn't seem to be the case (or, at least i couldn't get it working). I've also read a number of similar posts on this issue, but most are in C++ (which i do not understand), or didn't quite make sense to me.

How can i call the `reset` function if anything anywhere within the window is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

So i've been reading and reading and reading on event structure, primarily the `eventFilter` function, and many suggestions and examples of creating an object out of it, most examples however were in C++. Unfortunately I haven't been able to fully understand it, so made this little workaround:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


def update():
    window.reset()


class mybutton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setText("Press")

    def clickprint(self):
        print("hello2")


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.label = QLabel("0")
        self.button = mybutton()
        self.label2 = QLabel("TESTING")
        self.label2.setStyleSheet("background: orange;")

        self.button.pressed.connect(self.button.clickprint)
        self.button.pressed.connect(update)

        self.x = 0

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_label)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.x = 0

    def update_label(self):
        self.x += 1
        if self.x == 5:
            print("hello!")
        self.label.setText(str(self.x))
        print(self.x)

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 0


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have simply placed a function outside of any class that can be called by any object. The functions only command is to call the `reset` function inside `window`. It also means that every signal used for every element of the GUI, has to also have a second signal calling this `update` function.

While this works i feel like its a cheap solution that could be done better...